# HTTP POST from app.example.com to localhost: session cookie not sent

Tags: http, spring-mvc, cookies, spring-session

I have two Spring Web applications that work together. I'm running the first application from the IDE on localhost, while the second one is running in docker on app.127.0.0.1.nip.io.

The two applications interact indirectly through the users browser by redirecting and POSTing between the two apps. This is slightly similar to how an SP and an IdP work together in SAML2.

In my case, the first application on localhost is sending a 302 to the second application. After doing some work, the second application sends an HTML page with a form an JS code to autosubmit it, back to my first application on localhost. The HTML looks similar to this:

```
<form method=POST action="http://localhost:8080/some/path">
...
</form>
```

My first application is using Spring Session with a session cookie, and this works just fine. However, when the second application makes the browser POST the form, the browser *does not* send the session cookie with the POST request.

When both applications are running in docker under .127.0.0.1.nip.io, the cookie is sent.

I've tried to find any hint if this behaviour is expected, and what headers or other bits the applications could use to influence this.

At this point, this is mostly an annoyance while debugging, but I'm concerned that once the two applications will run on different FQDNs and/or different domains, the browsers will also block the cookie being sent.

I've tested this with current versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I think I'm running afould of SameSite cookie policies.

https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/
Cookies marked as SameSite=Lax will be sent on safe top-level navigations, e.g. clicking a link to go to a different site. However something like a <form> submission via POST to a different site would not include cookies.

It would seem that sending the cookie to localhost over HTTP (instead of HTTPS) will not work anymore with recent changes in the browsers.

Comment: So for a testing setup where I run the application from the IDE and use localhost to access it, I would need to start using 127.0.0.1.nip.io as well, or create a reverse proxy for TLS termination.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the new(ish) SameSite cookie policy that covers exactly this case: another application is POSTing to a host via HTTP. The default now is `SameSite: lax`, which does not allow sending the first-party cookie values on this request.

The solution is to allow the session cookie to be sent by specifying `SameSite: none`. Be aware however that this might create security vulnerabilities. For my application, this is not an issue, so I can allow the cookie to always be sent, and especially when I run my application in the debugger.

For the production deployment, I will be able to tighten this, since both applications will run under the same domain (a.example.com and b.example.com), and both will use TLS, so I can set the session cookie to `SameSite: lax`.

Here's a decent explanation: https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/